# JQuery regex checking length of an input's value not working

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the vague title, I had no idea how to call this weird 'error'.

I check an input with JQuery. The input value has to be no less than 5 characters.

(It display a red error message when the input 'nickname' 's length is below 5)

My regex : `[A-z0-9]{4}` (it starts to 0)

```
var nicknameError = false;

$('input[name=nickname]').keypress(function() {
    if($('input[name=nickname]').val().match("[A-z0-9]{4}"))
    {
        if(nicknameError)
        {
            nicknameError = false;
            $('form').find('.nicknameError').remove()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(!nicknameError)
        {
            $('input[name=nickname]').after("<span class = 'nicknameError'>Le pseudo est composé d'au minimum 5 lettres.</span>");
            nicknameError = true;
        }
    }
});
```

It works but it does bug when you start to erase few letters. Looks like it works when you write but not when you erase.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

try this?

```js
$('input[name=nickname]').on('input',function() {
    if(!$(this).val().match("[A-z0-9]{5}")){
        // less than 5 characters
        $('.nicknameError').show();
    }
    else{
        // 
        $('.nicknameError').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.nicknameError{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="nickname">
<span class = 'nicknameError'>Le pseudo est composé d'au minimum 5 lettres.</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer & your time. But I want to keep everything in the .js if possible & the keypress thing.

Comment: from keypress documentation: keypress indicates which character was entered. so you'd better use keyup or keydown to catch special keystrokes such as backspace. [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: did you just change keypress to keydown with your initial code above?

Comment: in your case, you'll compare the value **after** changed by press any key. but `keydown` fires before the value changes. so I suggest using `input` or `change` to check if the value is changed or not.